# can't create a folder from a shell script?

Tags: bash-scripting

I am trying to make a shell script that among other things will create a folder

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mkdir -m 1777 /home/steve/share
chown steve:steve /home/steve/share
```

This actually a part of a larger script to set up a new installation. But this line is not working

What I want is

```
/home/steve/share
```

What I get is:

```
drwxrwxrwt  2 steve steve 4096 Sep 29 11:56 'share'$'\r'/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your script newline encoding is Linux/Unix/LF. As I can see the folder name is `'share'$'\r'` that means that that there is extra `\r` at the end. Linux uses `\n` (LF) and Windows uses `\r\n` (CR LF) as  a newline character. Linux interprets line up to `\n`, thus extra `\r` in your folder name. You should be able to change newline in your editor.

Comment: You are right. I don't want to write a separate answer just to point out two important things, so use them to improve your answer if you wish. The things are: (1) The name of the directory is `share` plus a literal carriage return character; `'share'$'\r'` is just a [*representation*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/108618) modern `ls` uses to inform the user of this fact. (2) The right tool to fix the script is `dos2unix`.

Comment: Oops- I created tis file on the PC instead of using nano on the terminal....
Many thanks for the tips. (dos2unix fixed it).